# How to update UI from GLSurfaceView Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-view, glsurfaceview

I am working on a game and I am stumped on how to update my TextView that holds the score. In my Activity I have a TextView for the score and a GLSurfaceView. When the user gets puts in the game I want to be able to update the TextView in the same Activity.

I have tried using inflaters and Casting to type Activity as well as a few others. I know it should be possible however I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear why you're having trouble.  You should be able to update the TextView as you would in any other Activity, whether or not a GLSurfaceView happens to be present.  You just have to make sure that you issue the updates from the main UI thread, not the GLSurfaceView renderer thread.  An easy way to do this is to post a message to a Handler on the UI thread's Looper.

One example is [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "record GL app" Activity.  It uses a plain SurfaceView, rather than a GLSurfaceView, but the idea is the same.  The renderer thread periodically posts messages to the main UI thread with the current frame rate, which is placed in a TextView.

Comment: Thanks I missing a small part. That was a good reference though, appreciate it.